# Expect in Easymock calls the method actually, why is it so?

Tags: junit, easymock

```
 System.out.println("Check1");
 expect(mockobject.function(parameters)).andReturn("hello";
 System.out.println("check2***************************");
 replay(mockobject);
```

While executing the test, `the mockobject.function(parameters)` executes and call goes to the `method.Debugging` using the system out, it checks inside the function is also displayed in console.
Why is it so? The `expect()` doesn't allow the call to be made to the desired function?

Comment: sorry to miss the brackets expect(mockobject.function(parameters)).andReturn("hello");

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `mockobject` is a mock created with `mock()` or `createMock()` and not `partialMockBuilder()`, this can't happen unless `function` is final.